# How to convert log function in RStudio?

Tags: r, statistics

`fit1 = lm(price ~ . , data = car)`

`fit2 = lm(log(price) ~ . , data = car)`

I'm not sure how to convert log(price) to price in fit2 Won't it just become the same thing as fit1 if I do convert it? Please help.

Comment: `exp(fit2$fitted.values)` will give you a comparable result, but it will not be equal to `fit1$fitted.values`

Comment: Have a look at this answer on Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140713/making-predictions-with-log-log-regression-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a very simple example. Suppose I have some data points like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = (1:10)^2)
(p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point())
```

[image]

I want to try to fit a model to them, but don't know what form this should take. I try a linear regression first and plot the resultant prediction:

```r
mod1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
(p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = predict(mod1)), color = "blue"))
```

[image]

Next I try a linear regression on `log(y)`. Whatever results I get from predictions from this model will be predicted values of `log(y)`. But I don't want `log(y)` predictions, I want `y` predictions, so I need to take the 'anti-log' of the prediction. We do this in R by doing `exp`:

```r
mod2 <- lm(log(y) ~ x, data = df)
(p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = exp(predict(mod2))), color = "red"))
```

[image]

But we can see that we have different regression lines. That's because when we took the log of y, we were effectively fitting a straight line on the plot of log(y) against x. When we transform the axis back to a non-log axis, our straight line becomes an exponential curve. We can see this more clearly by drawing our plot again with a log-transformed y axis:

```r
p + scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, 500))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: fit2 <- lm(log(price) ~ ., data = car) ; pred <- exp(predict(fit2, newdata = validation)) Would that be correct with the exp?

Comment: That looks good @Mary - assuming `validation` is a list or data frame that contains the same variable names & types as `car`